# Button misfunction

Tags: java, android

When user click `Next` button, it suppose to show next record store in database, but when I run the app, user have to click `previous` button to view next entry and the `Next` button didn't perform any activity.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        int buttonId = v.getId();

        if (buttonId == R.id.buttonViewPrevious)
            if (currentBoothArrayIndex < boothArrayList.size() - 1) {
                displayBoothInformation(--currentBoothArrayIndex);
            } else if (buttonId == R.id.buttonViewNext)
                if (currentBoothArrayIndex < boothArrayList.size() - 1) {
                    displayBoothInformation(++currentBoothArrayIndex);
                } 
    }
```

Comment: On your line `if (buttonId == R.id.buttonViewPrevious)` there are no brackets after the if statement. Because there is more than 1 line of code below it, there needs to be brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `if else` construct is wrong. Try this:

```
if (buttonId == R.id.buttonViewPrevious){
   if (currentBoothArrayIndex < boothArrayList.size() - 1) {
     displayBoothInformation(--currentBoothArrayIndex);
   } 
}else if (buttonId == R.id.buttonViewNext){
   if (currentBoothArrayIndex < boothArrayList.size() - 1) {
     displayBoothInformation(++currentBoothArrayIndex);
   } 
}
```

Comment: The app crash when I clicked previous button.

Comment: Sorry, I have correct the code and now it's working. But the `Previous` button didn't show the previous entry.

Comment: that is a seperat problem and you should ask it seperatly.